# Multiple notification icons on one bar?

Tags: android

Is it possible to create a notification bar that contains multiple icons horizontally and each icon launches a separate service/activity?

Comment: Are you talking about replacing the stock notification bar in Android, or is it a custom notification bar inside your own application you want to make?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the pull down notification area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a notification only has a single `PendingIntent` (as seen in [this API method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)). You could conceivably create a [custom notification layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView) with multiple icons, but you could only launch one activity.

**Update:**

Actually if you read that doc carefully, it looks like as of API 11, you can do what you're trying to accomplish by setting [`RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) on your views in your custom layout!

Comment: I see.  Would it be possible to pass a variable to the one activity, but the variable changes depending on which icon is clicked?

Comment: Apparently it's changed in API 11, updated answer to reflect that.